# Jquery Datatable lost after selected index change dropdownlist asp.net update panel

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datatables

i have added jquery library to my gridview and it was really helpfull. when on page load this datatable show perfectly, but when I change value of dropdown list jquery datatable disapper. in this case, gridview just showing data based on dropdown list parameters value. I follow this [tutorial](https://www.aspforums.net/Threads/155443/Apply-Bootstrap-DataTable-Plugin-to-GridView-for-searching-paging-sorting-using-jQuery-in-ASPNet/).

link jquery reference:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.7/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.7/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

set javascript sintax to gridview:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //on page load
    $(function () {
        $('[id*=GridView1]').prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:first"))).DataTable({
            "responsive": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
        });
    });

</script>
```

here is my gridview asp.net:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" RenderMode="Inline">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name" 
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="30%" placeholder="select">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <br />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" class="table table-striped"
                    Width="100%" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" />
                        <asp:ButtonField CommandName="editRecord" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-info"
                            ButtonType="Button" Text="Edit" HeaderText="Edit Record" HeaderStyle-Width="10%">
                            <ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-info"></ControlStyle>
                        </asp:ButtonField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</form>
```

when I run this page,it worked:
[image]

BUT after i tried select one of value of dropdown list, datatable jquery didn't appear  any more.
[image]

need suggest for this issue and fix this. Thanks

Comment: You have to rebind your datatable after postback. It happens now only during load. After every postback rebind the table

Comment: how to implement it?

Comment: First, @H.Mikhaeljan's answer is correct.  The reason you are having this issue is because the `$(...)` function is only called once at the initial page load.  Calls due to the `UpdatePanel` and `DropDownList1`'s autopostback won't execute the script again.

Comment: See my answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48960734/how-to-add-datepicker-in-asp-net-gridview-control. There it is a DatePicker but the basic idea is the same.

Comment: @VDWWD it doesn't work. when i tried your comment on that thread my datatable can't be able to loaded when first time page load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You have to rebind your datatable after postback. It happens now only during load. After every postback rebind the table*

This is probably what you are searching for

`pageLoad()` will be triggered after every postback

```
function pageLoad() { 
         bindGrid();
};

function bindGrid(){
      $('[id*=GridView1]').prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:first"))).DataTable({
      "responsive": true,
      "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
   });
};
```

it does require to be on page.

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />
```

A other option instead of pageload is

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(bindGrid);
```

Comment: in my code above `ScriptManager` already exist. but the problem is I don't know how to rebind it.
so what the aim of `pageLoad()`function? cz it never call to any condition

Comment: pageLoad() is a function that gets called after partial postback

Comment: finally it worked for me... i don't knwo why after severals trying... but thanks for suggest me