# Jquery script sometimes work, sometimes doesn't

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I made script for my ASP.net page to validate values of few textboxes. The thing is, sometimes script works, sometimes do not. Here is my script:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {

           var _t1 = $(document.getElementById("<%=textbox5.ClientID%>"));
           var _t2 = $(document.getElementById("<%=textbox4.ClientID%>"));
           var _t3 = $(document.getElementById("<%=textbox10.ClientID%>"));
           var _t4 = $(document.getElementById("<%=textbox9.ClientID%>"));
           var _t5 = $(document.getElementById("<%=textbox15.ClientID%>"));
           var _t6 = $(document.getElementById("<%=textbox14.ClientID%>"));

           var _tLabel = $(document.getElementById("<%=IsMatch.ClientID%>"));

           if (_t1.val() < _t2.val()) {
               $(_tLabel).fadeIn('fast');
               $(_tLabel).html('ERROR ');
               $("#tg-yw4l-1").css("background-color", "red");
           }
           else if (_t3.val() < _t4.val()) {
               $(_tLabel).fadeIn('fast');
               $(_tLabel).html('ERROR');
               $("#tg-yw4l-2").css("background-color", "red");
           }
           else if (_t5.val() < _t6.val()) {
               $(_tLabel).fadeIn('fast');
               $(_tLabel).html('ERROR');
               $("#tg-yw4l-3").css("background-color", "red");
           }
           else {
               $(_tLabel).fadeOut('fast');
           }
       });
       </script>
```

What happens is that sometimes if requirements for error are met, it won't show error message and change backround.

Comment: so this line is not working $(_tLabel).html('ERROR ');??

Comment: Not sure why you're doing this: `$(document.getElementById("<%=textbox5.ClientID%>"));` - jQuery just needs a selector, like `$("#<%=textbox5.ClientID%>");`

Comment: Minimal, Complete, **Verifiable** code please.

Comment: jQuery doesnt have syntax like javascript

Comment: What happens probably is you do a postback. Then the ClientID changes. So the bindings are lost meaning you dont read the right values.I answered similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49432815/7324631). You have to reload the vars after a postback