# jQuery modal background gets darker

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net, modal-dialog

None of the responses I checked seems to have solved the problem I am facing.
I have a modal dialog that opens in response to a button click. I do some client side and some server side validation. Client side ones are OK but when I do a server side validation and re-show the modal, background gets darker with each failed validation (and re-showing of the modal).

I tried several CSS and js solutions suggested but none helped. There was one solutin that initially seemed to help (sort of) but when dialog was dismissed using Cancel button, none of the buttons on the page were clickable anymore.

This is what I have:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addEditModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="catModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog fade in">
        <div class="modal-content">    
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><span id="spnAddEditHeader"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">  
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                        <div class="eaTool input-group">
                            <label for="tbName">Tool Name</label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbName" CssClass="form-control" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                            <span runat="server" id="lblErrToolName" clientidmode="static" class="field-validation-error pull-left" style="display:none"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4" style="vertical-align:bottom;padding-top:20px">
                        <div id="divNewButtons" style="text-align: center;">
                            <button id="btnNewToolCancel" class="btn btn-info2" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" aria-label="Cancel" >Cancel</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                             <button id="btnNewToolSubmit" class="btn btn-primary" aria-hidden="true" aria-label="Submit" >Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" id="btnNewTool" onclick="showNew();">Add New Tool</button>

function showNew() {
    clear();
    $("#spnAddEditHeader").text("Add New Tool");

    $('#addEditModal').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });
    $('#addEditModal').modal('show');
}

$(document).on("click", "#btnNewToolSubmit", function (event) {
    var isValid = validateSubmit();

    if (isValid) {
        __doPostBack('btnNewToolSubmit', "submitNew");
        $('#addEditModal').modal('hide');
    }
    else
        return false;
});
```

in .cs file:

```
protected void AddTool()
{
    string sToolName = tbName.Text.Trim();
    bool bNameExists = ToolsData.ToolNameExists(sToolName);

    if (bNameExists)
    {
        lblErrToolName.InnerText = "A tool by same name alreay exists.";
        lblErrToolName.Style["display"] = "inline";          

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "showNewModal", "$('#addEditModal').modal('show');", true);
    }
    else
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

I tried:

```
.modal-backdrop + .modal-backdrop {
    opacity : 0;
}
.modal-backdrop:nth-child(2n-1) {
    opacity : 0;
}
```

Also, using js:

```
$(".modal").on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
    if ($(".modal-backdrop").length > 1) {
        $(".modal-backdrop").not(':first').remove();
    }
})
```

Comment: Are you using an UpdatePanel?

Comment: yes. Modal content is wrapped by an update panel.When I set the error label text and visibility, I update the update panel and then issue script manager API

Comment: Then you are probably not removing the old modal. The new modal is displayed on top and because you stack the backgrounds, one modal seems to be getting darker. Could that be your problem?

Comment: it sounds right and makes sense. How do I resolve it? I guess in the server side when I show the modal in response to error I have to remove it first and open it again but how? Also, would closing and opening clear the data already present inside modal dialog?

Comment: Use the ScriptManager to destroy the object in code behind, or check the `add_endRequest` of the `PageRequestManager`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48960734/how-to-add-datepicker-in-asp-net-gridview-control